# Fastest Way to Access MongoDB through Jetty

Tags: java, mongodb, jetty

I have a web app that I'm running through AngularJS, my server side is run through jetty and my database is MongoDB. Right now, the way I have my webapp accessing the database is through websockets, but I feel that this is probably not the best/fastest way to do this, because I've found it takes a very large amount of time to process the data. So I'm wondering what the best way to access my data is through javascript, jetty, and mongodb. Thanks!
Browser Code:

```
getDataWebsocket.onmessage= function(event){
                var data = "[{" +
                event.data.substring(0, event.data.length-1) +
                "]";
                $scope.data = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(JSON.parse(data));
                console.log($scope.data);
            };
```

Jetty Code

```
try {
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
                DB db = mongoClient.getDB("MyDB");
                DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("MyCollection");
                DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
                String data = "";
                while (cursor.hasNext()){
                    DBObject next = cursor.next();
                    data += (JSON.serialize(next)).toString() + ",";
                }
                data = data.substring(0, data.length());
                sendMessage(data, session);
            }catch(Exception e){
                sendMessage(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), session);
                System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Could you attach any code, data and requests examples?

Comment: What strikes my eye is that you get and send all documents from your collection. If the collection is big it can be quite time-consuming. Do you really need all the data at once, wouldn't it be better to use pagination? Moreover all data is parsed on the client side, that also takes time.

Comment: For my application, I will need all the data from the start, so pagination wouldn't really be an option. As far as parsing the data on the server side goes, websockets only have three forms of communication (strings, typed arrays, and blobs), so I wouldn't be able to send a json from the server via websockets. I'm inexperienced with databases so I'm wondering if websockets are really the best way to achieve database communication.

Comment: Java driver uses its own wire protocol to connect to the database. What protocol to use to establish communication between the server and your client (AngularJS) is your choice to make. You can use http or websocket if your server has to push data to the client (which does not seem to be the case).

Comment: For the sake of curiosity, could you explain why you need all the data from the start?

Comment: I'm not allowed to discuss a lot of the details, but it's a visualization of data, and the user wants to be able to view all of the data at one time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish what you are doing is to write a REST service that calls a java class to access the MongoDB. Take a look a simple application using AngularJS, Jetty, MongoDB here https://github.com/pmkent/angular-bootstrap-java-rest